# How can a default site icon be set in customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer, icon

From my research there are only two questions I've found around this topic on this site:

- [How to change in customizer the “site identity” tab required capabilities](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206907/how-to-change-in-customizer-the-site-identity-tab-required-capabilities)
- [how to change default icon of custom plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84200/how-to-change-default-icon-of-custom-plugin)

outside of the site I did find:

- [How to Add a Default Site Icon in Theme's Customizer](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/how-to-add-a-default-site-icon-in-themes-customizer)

but when I try:

```
function default_icon() {
  global $wp_customize;
  $wp_customize->get_setting('site_icon',array (
    'default' => home_url() . 'img/test.png'
  ));
}
add_action('customize_register','default_icon');
```

I've also tried `add_setting` with:

```
function default_icon() {
  global $wp_customize;
  $wp_customize->add_setting('site_icon', array(
    'default' => home_url() . 'img/test.png'
));
}
add_action('customize_register','default_icon');
```

but that doesn't work either. It will not show the default icon in the drag and drop area and renders "No Image selected":

[image]

In my functions.php how can I code my theme to render the default icon presently being used in the drag and drop area?

After further testing I can set the `default when I code`:

```
add_action('customize_register','default_icon',10,2);
```

and I can see it in a dump of `$wp_customize` but as far as rendering it will not.

Comment: Could you post your code with add_setting? It should work fine.

Comment: It's the same as above but with just `add_setting`.

Comment: Hmm, do you have to set default value for that setting? Would displaying your custom icon when no icon is set be enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the customizer API to set default icon. This should do the trick, I guess:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'site_icon' , array(
        'default'     => get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/logo.png',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but I've already tried that approach, edited question to show code, also note that you need to call `global $wp_customize` or you'll error out.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ You're right. It works in that sense it really sets the default value for that setting - you can see it var_dumping `$wp_customize` object, but it doesn't change the value of control...

Comment: Ya but that still doesn't solve the question

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I know - I’ll leave it here so I can get back to it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

The site icon is not a theme setting, so the the theme should not be supplying a default.

edit:
source: [Wordpress Theme Handbook - Customizer Objects](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/)

> Note: themes generally should not modify core sections and panels with the get methods, since themes should not modify core, theme-agnostic functionality. Plugins are encouraged to use these functions where necessary. Themes should not “reorganize” customizer sections that aren’t added by the theme.

Comment: Isn't it annoying when you get down voted with no explanation? True, your answer wasn't super helpful and could have been expanded upon – notably with references supporting your argument. The wordpress team have included a site icon upload option by default and have expressly asked theme authors not to modify default customizer settings so you're on point. Bumping your answer +1 for adhering to Wordpress theme guidelines. Going to edit your answer to include a relevant passage from the WP Theme Handbook.